# iMessage app error itms-90639 "invalid binary"

Tags: emoji, imessage

I have an emoji keyboard app selling on the app store and I'm trying to replace it with the new IOS 10 iMessaging app and keep getting this error. Anyone seen this issue? See picture below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTBAW.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error when trying to upload a new version of app (which has a stand alone app and an iMessage extension). The problem is that you are trying to archive a specific target not the whole project.

- Make sure that there is a device attached.
- select your main project in the Project and Targets list
- set your scheme to the main scheme (not the extension)
- archive your project

It should not upload without an error

Comment: yes, and I uploaded other projects as well with no issues following these steps